# Button won't respond when execute the setInterval function

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to have the second button ( "free five") to keep checking the condition that it would reappear when the number reached 5 again after I clicked it. However, it never showed up again after I pressed it, unless I press the first button.

Game instruction is in the p section.

```js
let birdNum = document.getElementById("birdNum")
let catchBtn = document.getElementById("catch")
let freeBtn = document.getElementById("free")

function catchBird() {
  birdNum.innerHTML++;

  if (birdNum.innerHTML > 4) {
    freeBtn.classList.add("fadeIn");
    freeBtn.disabled = false;
  }
}

document.getElementById("catch").addEventListener("click", catchBird);

function freeBird() {
  birdNum.innerHTML -= 5;

  setInterval(() => {
    birdNum.innerHTML++;
  }, 1000);

  if (birdNum.innerHTML <= 4) {
    freeBtn.classList.remove("fadeIn");
    freeBtn.disabled = true;
  }
}

document.getElementById("free").addEventListener("click", freeBird);
```

```css
#free {
  opacity: 0;
}

#free.fadeIn {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<P>
  press "catch one" to catch one bird. <br> press "free five" to free five bird. <br>
  <br> Once you free five birds, they will come back with their kids, one bird per second.
</P>

<span id="birdNum">0</span>
<button id="catch">
catch one
</button>

<button id="free" disabled=t rue>
free five
</button>
```

Comment: I put your code as snippet. And what is your issue ? What is your question ?

Comment: sorry for not specifying the question! The problem is that I would like the second button to reappear by itself after I clicked it and wait for the number to reach five. Apparently, it would not reappear and I have to click the first button to make it appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code, see if it works for you:

**Edit:** I realised your issue, I edited to work now.

So in your code, you were only checking whether or not to make the 'free' button visible once. And you only checked when it was pressed. For example, we are playing your game and get to 6. We press the 'free birds' button and we go down to one and the 'free birds' button disappears. Now the `setInterval` keeps making the number of birds go up. We get to 5 and the button does not reappear because we are not running any code to make it reappear. In the `setInterval`, as well as incrementing the counter, we need to check whether or not we can make the 'free birds' button visible again. See the `resetInterval()` function. In the setInterval's `callback`, we are now checking whether of not the birds counter is above 5. If the condition returns true, we will show the 'free birds' button.

With the below JS, it should work nicely.

```js
const birdNum = document.getElementById("birdNum");
const catchBtn = document.getElementById("catch");
const freeBtn = document.getElementById("free");

const initialTimeout = 1000;
let timesBirdsFreed = 0;

let intervalId;

function resetInterval(delay) {
  if (delay < 10) delay = 10;

  if (intervalId) clearInterval(intervalId);
  
  intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    birdNum.innerHTML++;

    // if statement from catch bird function is needed here too
    if (birdNum.innerHTML >= 5) {
      freeBtn.classList.add("fadeIn");
      freeBtn.disabled = false;
    }
  }, delay);
}

function catchBird() {
  birdNum.innerHTML++;

  if (birdNum.innerHTML >= 5) {
    freeBtn.classList.add("fadeIn");
    freeBtn.disabled = false;
  }
}

catchBtn.addEventListener("click", catchBird);

function freeBird() {
  timesBirdsFreed++;
  birdNum.innerHTML -= 5;

  resetInterval(initialTimeout/timesBirdsFreed);

  if (birdNum.innerHTML <= 4) {
    freeBtn.classList.remove("fadeIn");
    freeBtn.disabled = true;
  }
}

freeBtn.addEventListener("click", freeBird);
```

```css
#free {
  opacity: 0;
}

#free.fadeIn {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Bird Game</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>press "catch one" to catch one bird. <br> press "free five" to free five bird. <br><br> Once you free five birds, they will come back with their kids, one bird per second.</p>

    <span id="birdNum">0</span>

    <button id="catch">catch one</button>
    <button id="free" disabled=true>free five</button>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Edit 2: Further explanation and added links to `setInterval()` method and `clearInterval()` method.**

```
function resetInterval(delay) {
  // if delay is too small (less than 10 ms) make delay 10 ms
  if (delay < 10) delay = 10;

  // in beginning of the program, intervalId is undefined
  // so we will only use clearInterval if intervalId is not undefined (if we've used setInterval already) 
  if (intervalId) clearInterval(intervalId);
  
  // use setInterval method with a delay which was passed to the function as an argument
  intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    // make birds go up by one
    birdNum.innerHTML++;

    // if statement from catch bird function is needed here too
    // (if birds counter is 5 or more, show 'free birds' button)
    if (birdNum.innerHTML >= 5) {
      freeBtn.classList.add("fadeIn");
      freeBtn.disabled = false;
    }
  }, delay);
  // all of this resets the interval but at a smaller delay so birds go up faster each time
}
```

The `resetInterval()` function just stops an existing `setInterval()` from executing code by using `clearInterval(intervalId)` which uses the ID returned when `setInterval()` when it was called. An ID can be, for example, `239` or maybe `146`. After the existing `setInterval()` was cleared, another `setInterval()` is called and its ID is stored in the variable (`intervalId`) to be used to clear the new `setInterval()` the next time `resetInterval()` is called (the next time you free five birds). The difference though is with each call of the `resetInterval()` function, the setInterval's delay which was passed into the function is smaller, making the number of birds go up faster.

The way this is done is when the resetInterval function is called, a delay is passed into the function as a parameter like so `resetInterval(initialTimeout/timesBirdsFreed)`. `initialTimeout` is set to always be 1000 (milliseconds). `timesBirdsFreed` is a number which tells you how many times you clicked the 'free birds' button. **If you clicked 'free birds' once**, `initialTimeout/timesBirdsFreed` will be `1000/1` which is 1000 (ms). So the first time you clicked 'free birds', **the number of birds will go up by one bird every second**. **The second time you click 'free birds'**, `initialTimeout/timesBirdsFreed` will be `1000/2` which is 500 (ms), meaning now **birds will go up by one every half a second**.
Because of this, the more you click 'free birds', the faster they will go up (up to a limit - smallest delay possible is 10ms, so it won't go any faster than that).

**References**

1. MDN Web Docs

   - [`setInterval()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval)
2. W3Schools

   - [`setInterval()` method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)
   - [`clearInterval()` method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)

Comment: Hello, thank you for the code! But I am not sure if it is what am I looking for. So, when the number reached 5, I would like the second button to appear; then, the number should go back to 0, and slowly go up to 5 again.  I would like the second button to appear after the number reached 5 the second time, however, it wouldn't. It would be really helpful if you could give me some advice. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Hi @AndrevKurkov, I've converted the code into a snippet. I tested it and it seems to show the 'free birds' button fine without having to click the 'catch' button first. Although I don't know if you intended for the birds to increase faster as you keep clicking the 'free birds' button. I added that functionality because in your original post you kept calling ```setInterval``` which made birds increase faster as you kept clicking 'free birds'.

Comment: Mr.Khalish, this is awesome! Making birds come back faster is a great concept, plus it helps me learn more about Javascript. Thank you, good sir!

Comment: Good evening! I have a follow-up question. What does ` resetInterval(initialTimeout/timesBirdsFreed)` mean?

Comment: Hi, sorry for this quite late reply. I have added a further explanation on what ```resetInterval()``` does as well as some links if you want to learn a bit more. Hope it answers your question! Enjoy your day!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to stop the `setInterval` you should keep its instance and then call `clearInterval(instance)`

I'm not sure what you want to achieve but you may get the idea from the this code:

```
  let intervalInstance;
  function freeBird() {

    birdNum.innerHTML -= 5;

    if (intervalInstance) {
      clearInterval(intervalInstance);
    }
    intervalInstance = setInterval(() => {
      birdNum.innerHTML++;
    }, 1000);

    if (birdNum.innerHTML <= 4) {
      freeBtn.classList.remove("fadeIn");
      freeBtn.disabled = true;
    }
  }
```